# Windows Phone SDK - Cannot use FacebookClient.get() method

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk

I am using the facebook SDK in the Visual Studio 2010
I install the packagae using the package manager (install-package -pre facebook)
This installs the 6.0.3 Alpha version.
I am trying to write for the Windows Phone 7.1 OS
I use the:

var FacebookClient fb = new FacebookClient()

I want to use the method

fb.get()

But this does not show up in the Windows Phone Project.
It does show up in the Windows Forms Project.

Any idea why I can use fb.get() in the windows form project but not in windows phone project?

Thanks
 Steve

Answer (score 0):

Facebook C# SDK for Silverlight/WindowsPhone/WinRT does not support synchronous methods.

You will need to use the async alternatives instead. `GetAsync`, `PostAsync` or `DeleteAsync`.